# why html5boilerplate is stuck to V5.3.0 with old version of all Bootstrap, normalize & modernizr?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modernizr, html5boilerplate, normalize, normalize-css

I just noticed that when I download html5boilerplate V5.3.0 it comes with

1. Bootstrap v3.3.1 (but Bootstrap v3.3.7 is available)
2. normalize.css v3.0.2 (but normalize.css 7.0.0 is available)
3. modernizr 2.8.3 respond 1.4.2 (but modernizr 3.5 is available)

so why html5boilerplate come with old version of Bootstrap, normalize & modernizr ?
Can I update latest version of all Bootstrap, normalize & modernizr on my own ? will that break any settings of html5boilerplate ? is it safe to update all Bootstrap, normalize & modernizr on my own ?

Again how can I update Bootstrap, normalize & modernizr into html5boilerplate ? any shortcut or something ?

or html5boilerplate is old thing now ? anything new and better then html5boilerplate came in ?

Usefull links :
1. https://html5boilerplate.com/
2. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
3. http://getbootstrap.com/
4. https://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I shared on the Github repo, if you download the project from Github you get updated versions of almost everything (minus Modernizr which is one PR away from being updated.) Also, we're looking to release 6.0 sooner rather than later. I [just need some help](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1880) getting the last few issues cleared (I'm the only active developer right now and... I'm super busy with work.)

Comment: thanks for quick response sir. again as you have suggested I have downloaded H5BP from GitHub. but I'm very new to GitHub so I'm getting confused. inside download from GitHub I have folder named "dist". according to my guess that is the only folder I need right? should I use "dist" folder ? and delete all the other files and folders outside of that "dist" ?

Comment: question 2. is I have checked that "dist" folder also. inside of that also. version of normalize.css is 5.0.0 n latest version is 7.0.0. so should I download normalize.css from official website and replace that normalize.css file inside of "dist/css" folder? would that break anything? any setup of H5BP will be Disturbed? or clash? should I wait for you to update normalize.css version inside of H5BP coz you need to integrate something for updating normalize.css?

Comment: question 3. which is a last stable version of H5BP ? one which I can download from H5BP official website ? or one which is from GitHub with new version of all normalize.css and etc ?